# Is there way to configure SSL/TLS per Protocol cipher suite configuration in any web server?

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, server, tls1.2

Is there way to have different cipher suite configurations for different SSL/TLS versions?
For eg. I want to have different cipher suites for TLS 1.1 and different suites for TLS 1.0

So If client supports TLS 1.0 as highest protocol, different suites will be preferred